# List Mailchimp Current Member Counts in Dashboard

Tags: reporting, dashboard, nonprofit-starter-pack

I'd like to create a dashboard that shows administrators the current Mailchimp Lists by name and their current total subscribers. Is this something I can do with the Dashboard configurator alone, or am I going to have to create a VisualForce page? Or is there a dashboard for this already configured?

Using: Salesforce for Non Profits, Mailchimp for Salesforce has been installed from the AppExchange. These are the default reports installed by MC for SF from the appexchange: All Recent Activity by Campaign, Recent Opens by List, Recent Unsubscribes By List, Recent Unsubscribes By List. But I don't see in the defaults a simple list of my existing Mailchimp Lists with total current members in each list in dashboard form. This is something I should be able to do. How can I make this happen?

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE Chris. Please take the time to visit the [Help] and take our [Tour] to better understand how this forum works, including [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). I don't use Mailchimp myself, but I'd expect you'll need to tell us more about where your data is located in order for someone to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! You're absolutely right. Allow me to specify.
Using: Salesforce for Non Profits, Mailchimp for Salesforce has been installed from the AppExchange. 

These are the default reports installed by MC for SF from the appexchange:
All Recent Activity by Campaign,
Recent Opens by List,
Recent Unsubscribes By List,
Recent Unsubscribes By List.

But I don't see in the defaults a simple list of my existing Mailchimp Lists with total current members in each list in dashboard form.
This is something I should be able to do.

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Before you can use or create a new Dashboard, you first need to create and run a Report. The Report is then linked to the Dashboard as it's data source.

On the [Reports and Dashboards Quick Start Page](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewQuickStarts?id=000113375&language=en_US), you'll find a short YouTube video titled [Getting Started with Report Builder](https://youtu.be/7_LkmrhKf2g) along with numerous other links that should help get you going to help you understand how to use the templates you have. One thing you'll want to remember to do is is to use "SaveAs" if you modify any of the MailChip reports or Dashboards that came with the AppExchange package so you'll still have the originals.

To gain a more thorough understanding of the material through an interactive tutorial, I highly recommend you visit Trailhead and go through the [Reports & Dashboards Module](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/reports_dashboards).